# Fuzzy matching in R - about 1 million rows

Tags: r, pattern-matching, bigdata

I have a list of about one million individuals - each of which is identified by his/her name and surname. Individuals might be present in the list more than once. I would like to group observations by individual and count how many times they appear - this is usually OK and do it with `dplyr::group_by`.

However, there are spelling mistakes. In order to solve the issue, I thought of computing a measure of string distance within this list. I would then go ahead and assume that if the string distance is below a certain threshold, record identify the same individual. 
All the methods I tried so far are either too time-consuming or plain infeasible RAM-wise. 
These is my attempt using `dplyr` and `RecordLinkage`:

```
list_matrix <- expand.grid(x = individual_list, pattern = individual_list, stringsAsFactors = F)
# The same is achieved using stringdistmatrix (stringdist package)
result <- list_matrix %>% 
          group_by(x) %>% 
          mutate(similarity = levenshteinSim(x, pattern)) %>%
          summarise(match = similarity[which.max(similarity)], 
                    matched_to = pattern[which.max(match)])
```

This method works well with small data sets. Intuitively, I always confront all elements with each other. Nevertheless, the resulting matrix is of dimension *numberofrows* x *numerofrows*, which in my case is a million times a million - way too heavy to be handled. 
I also gave a shot to other functions: `adist`, `pmatch`, `agrep(l)`. Same logic applies. I think that the problem is conceptual here. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe order individuals (alphabetically?) and compare only `n` (100? 1000?) rows above and below? It will still be extremely time consuming, but much lower on a RAM usage.

Comment: A small example would be useful

Comment: I'd recommend looking at `compare.dedup` in the `RecordLinkage` package.